# Why are my default options not being checked off in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, multivalue

Why is it that when I set up a multi value parameter in SSRS and default the value to more than one default value, those values are not checked off when the report runs?

My parameter gets its values from a query specified in "Available Values". That works just fine. When I run the report one check box is selected by default in the drop down. But when I default the value of the parameter to two or more values, then no options are checked off.

For example, say my query returns:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

Then say I default the value to **B**. Then A through F show in the drop down, when the report runs, and B is checked off. But if I set **B** and **D** as Default Values, then nothing is checked, just the A through F appear as options in the drop down, but none are selected. Why is this? Please help.

Comment: Are you sure your dataset is returning the same values that you set as default values? check if the dataset field you are using doesn't contain leading and trailing whitespaces.

Comment: @alejandrozuleta, they absolutely match. I stripped off all the formatting and also made sure that the values are exactly the same

Comment: Where do you check running report? Locally or deployed to server?

Comment: Values in multi select are case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that I was defaulting some values that were not results returned in the query. Have to make sure you default values that are available, otherwise this happens.